# Can I bypass an intermediate object in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have top level entities TRACK, MEDIA_GROUP and MEDIA, each with an integer primary key.  I also have a join table from TRACK to MEDIA_GROUP which is 1:1 and MEDIA has a FK column into MEDIA_GROUP.  I'm trying to find a way in hibernate to map a collection of Media directly into the Track object, bypassing the creation of a MediaGroup object.

Basically I want to turn this:

```
TRACK <-> MEDIA_TRACK_MAP <-> MEDIA_GROUP <-> MEDIA
```

into this:

```
TRACK <-> MEDIA_TRACK_MAP <-> MEDIA
```

But the join column between MEDIA_TRACK_MAP and MEDIA isn't the primary key of MEDIA.

Comment: What is the role of media_group at the java level?

Comment: To collect a set of MEDIA objects together so that they could be attached to Track (or another kind of object, using another join table.  It also stores a number of other top level properties which aren't really relevant to the task I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer here is 'No' unless you're willing to do some hacks by mapping SQL queries instead of tables.  The only other alternative is to create a view that performs the join.